# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir el XML que genera zeep para consultar una API SOAP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, soap, zeep

Necesito ayuda para saber si estoy generando bien las llamadas a una API Soap.

Estoy usando la librería [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) de Python que supuestamente se usa para esto pero no tengo muy claro cómo funciona tampoco.

El caso es que esta API necesita una cabecera SOAP que obtengo de esta manera:

```
cabecera = client.get_type('ns0:AuthHeader')
cabeza_valores = cabecera(login='login',pwd='contraseña', 
Id_CodFacturacion='Codigo', 
Nombre_Cargue='Prueba')
```

Según he leído en la documentación debería de generarlo así.

Por otro lado debo generar un pedido, que lo hago de la misma manera.
Al llamar al servicio lo llamo de esta manera:

```
resultado=client.service.CargueMasivoExterno(_soapheaders[cabeza_valores],envios=datos)
```

Y esto me devuelve un array con un campo `False`, refiriendose a que la llamada no se ha hecho bien, y me devuelve todos los datos.

Necesito poder imprimir de alguna manera el XML que me genera para saber cómo lo está maquetando y enviando.

Comment: Aqui http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html te explica cómo escribir un plugin que será invocado antes de enviar el XML al servidor, y desde el que puedes imprimirlo/guardarlo, etc.

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba y no sabia donde encontrarlo

Comment: He encontrado el error pero no sé como solucionarlo, el problema es que necesito añadir xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" a la cabecera del xml pero no sé como puedo añadirlo con la librería ZEEP

Comment: Entiendo que el plugin, a través de `egress()`, recibe en `envelope` el XML que se va a enviar. Supongo que se tratará de un objeto de tipo `etree.Element`, y que puedes usar los métodos de ese objeto para modificarlo (añadir atributos sería tu caso), antes de retornarlo. Mírate la documentación de [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta correcta a tu prengunta esta en el sguiente [Link](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/client.html#creating-the-raw-xml-documents), alli se explica como generar el xml y devolverlo para visualizar.